# bash: character that fires the execution of an user defined program

Tags: bash, special-characters

Is it possible in bash while typing a shell command to have a characters that fires an user defined program?

For example, the user types at shell prompt

cp

and then types a special character that fires a program allowing to navigate the file system to find the copy command source file.

The programs return the selected file name that is appended to shell cp command.

Now the user types again the special character that fires the same program as above to navigate the file system for finding the destination file or folder.

At this point the command is ready to be sent to bash for execution

Comment: sounds like shell completion. google for bash completion for example, in this case `tab` - is the special symbol, however no idea if one can redefine that.

Comment: Do you really need to provide functionality at shell level? Why don't you implement whatever you need at command/bash function level?